# RabbitMQ - Error trying to enable plugins

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, windows-10

I'm pretty new to RabbitMQ so just installed rabbitmq-server-3.6.1 with Erlang_otp_win64_18.2.1 on Windows 10. I'm trying to run the following commands through admin command prompt:

> cd "\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\sbin"
>
> C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.1\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

But I get the following error:

> {"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_nodes,ensure_epmd,[],[]},{rabbit_cli,start_distribution,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,152}]},{rabbit_cli,ensure_cli_distribution,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,49}]},{rabbit_cli,main,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,62}]},{init,start_it,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1035}]}]}}
> init terminating in do_boot ()

I originally installed RabbitMQ and Erlang on Win7 where these commands worked just fine. I upgraded to Win10 and reinstalled both Erlang and RabbitMQ and ever since I've been getting the error. I've tried doing multiple clean installs of both programs (as Admin), clearing away registry entries and residual folders but still getting the above error. I don't quite understand what is causing it so if anyone can help I would be grateful!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think, rabbit want to tell you that "ensure_epmd -> undef", maybe you don't start epmd (erlang port map daemon)? I don't know, how start it in windows, but in linux you first need execute epmd in console, or something like 'systemctl enable epmd & systemctl start epmd'

Comment: >C:\Program Files\erl7.2.1\erts-7.2.1\bin>epmd -names
epmd: up and running on port 4369 with data:
name RabbitMQ at port 25120 so the process is running with rabbitmq but when I try to run rabbitmqctl start I get >{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_nodes,ensure_epmd,[],[]},{rabbit_cli,start_distribution,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"}... Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Another thing I just noticed is that epmd is failing to bind to the socket so this may be the cause, any ideas why it wouldn't bind? C:\Program Files\erl7.2.1\erts-7.2.1\bin>epmd -debug
epmd: Fri Jun 03 11:23:07 2016: epmd running - daemon = 0
epmd: Fri Jun 03 11:23:07 2016: failed to bind socket